# Stream audio from Linux to Raspbmc

Tags: fedora, audio, raspberry-pi, streaming

I'd like to stream audio (mainly Spotify) to my Raspberry Pi. I am running Fedora 19 and Raspbmc is running on the Raspberry Pi. I'd like to stream wireless.

My first thought was to use AirPlay, as XBMC already supports it. However, they are using v2 which does not seem to work with Shairport, which seems to be the only solution to stream from my Linux laptop.

I am open to use another protocol than AirPlay. However, I would very much like it to be integrated with XBMC.

Is there some solution to achieve this? Bonus would be if I also could stream video.

Comment: I think Raspmc does not use pulseaudio by default, but it is available, correct?  I would not suggest using it just for this purpose, but if you are using it already on Raspmc, Fedora does use it by default and there are various ways to serve sound from one pulseaudio system to another -- leave a comment @goldilocks here if you are using it and I can explain.

Comment: Do you know spotimc? It seems limited for the moment but it is a fairly new project https://github.com/mazkolain/spotimc

Comment: @rMistero Yes, I do know it and I do use it. However, I don't want to switch between controlling my Raspberry (via remote) and my laptop all the time (instead just using the Spotify version on my PC and stream it to Raspbmc). Also, Artists and top lists are still missing for Spotimc

Comment: I'm told pulseaudio can route audio over a network, but I've never found a good example of how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I'd give [Mopidy](http://docs.mopidy.com/en/latest/) a try.

> Mopidy is a music server which can play music both from multiple sources, like your local hard drive, radio streams, and from Spotify and SoundCloud. Searches combines results from all music sources, and you can mix tracks from all sources in your play queue. Your playlists from Spotify or SoundCloud are also available for use.

It lists Spotify as one of the services that it supports.

> Mopidy is a music server which can play music both from multiple sources, like your local hard drive, radio streams, and from Spotify and SoundCloud.

It also has good details for [installing it on a Rasp Pi](http://docs.mopidy.com/en/latest/installation/raspberrypi/).

> Mopidy runs nicely on a Raspberry Pi. As of January 2013, Mopidy will run with Spotify support on both the armel (soft-float) and armhf (hard-float) architectures, which includes the Raspbian distribution.

It also exposes its interface through a [HTTP frontend](http://docs.mopidy.com/en/latest/ext/http/#ext-http) which can then be controlled using one of the [HTTP clients](http://docs.mopidy.com/en/latest/clients/http/#http-clients).

Comment: Am I able to integrate this in any way into XBMC (as stated, this is important to me)? From the documentation it doesn't look that way, but I haven't tried it yet...

Comment: @dirkk - integrate it how? Do you mean as a source that you can navigate via the GUI in XBMC?

Comment: @sim mostly that the currently running sound is stopped when I start streaming, maybe the visualization is displayed or some sort of "currently streaming". Basically the same should happen as when I stream using my Android device, which works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

If I may, I suggest you test my tool named Idok.

http://metal3d.github.io/idok

It can stream local media (music, audio...) or streams, or whatever is streamable to your XBMC inteface. It can serve media from a opened port, or through SSH Tunnel.

There is an easy installation script, it should run nicely.